# Translating cURL API into an R request

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I'm trying to create a script in R that utilizes an API. In standard `cURL` format, the request looks like this:

```
curl --request GET \
     --url https://api.test.com/v4/Questions/54949 \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic XXXX123456789'
```

When I use the `httr` package, I try running this request:

```
get_data <- GET("https://api.test.com/v4/Questions/54949", add_headers(authorization = 'XXXX123456789'))
```

But I'm met with the following when I check what's stored in `get_data`:

```
Response [https://api.test.com/v4/Questions/54949]
  Date: 2021-08-03 18:59
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 247 B
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
      "text": "The request could not be authorized because a session is not present, an Authentication header was n...
    }
  ]
```

What am I missing? Am I running the `GET` requests wrong?

EDIT: Based on @hobo's answer, I tried:

```
    GET(
  "https://api.securevan.com/v4/surveyQuestions/441560",
  accept_json(),
  add_headers(Authorization = 'Basic 7x99x744-x69x-8956-x44x-4544xx7x7481'))
```

But I still got the same response?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed you'd updated the question.  I'm now pretty sure your code matches the original question, so I just ran the cURL with the Authorization header from your last update.  It returns HTML, not JSON.  The HTML contains "DOSarrest Internet Security", so it's possible you've tripped the site's DDoS protection.  Maybe your account's been disabled?  And while it helped me check, it's probably not a good idea to post actual Auth credentials - that's like posting your user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing "Basic" in your header.  This works:

```
GET(
  "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd",
  add_headers(authorization = paste0('Basic ', jsonlite::base64_enc('user:passwd')))
)
```

Though I'd be tempted to use the `authenticate` function - just looks cleaner to me:

```
GET(
  "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd",
  authenticate("user", "passwd")
)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your follow-ups, try the following, which (I think) will match your original cURL:

```
GET(
  "https://api.test.com/v4/Questions/54949",
  accept_json(),
  add_headers(Authorization = 'Basic XXXX123456789'))
)
```

Comment: please see my edit, I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Ah - sorry I wasn't clear.  You don't need to encode your token - it's already encoded.  You're just missing "Basic", so it should just be `add_headers(authorization = 'Basic XXXX123456789')` instead of `add_headers(authorization = 'XXXX123456789')`

Comment: I just tried `GET(
  "https://api.secure.com/v4/surveyQuestions/331816",
  add_headers(authorization = 'Basic 5f68f511-x36x-1234-x94x-9493xx83'))`

And got:

 `"errors": [
    {
      "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
      "text": "An error has occurred."
    }
  ]`

Comment: I assume "5f68f511-x36x-1234-x94x-9493xx83" is the same string as "XXXX123456789" in your cURL request?  In which case, you may have got past the authentication problem, but you might need to add another header for the `'Accept: application/json'` part of your cURL.

Comment: You could check that by retrying the cURL without the `--header 'Accept: application/json' \ ` portion

Comment: Hmmm just tried that and still got the `BAD_REQUEST` code... any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your current code to your question?  We need to work out if it's the authentication piece, or something after that.  If you run your cURL command without the `--header 'Accept: application/json' \ ` portion, do you get a "BAD REQUEST" response?  If so, you need to make sure you're passing that header correctly.  If you don't get a "BAD REQUEST", there's probably a problem with the authorization header.  if you assign the result of your request to `r`, (`r <- GET(...`), does `str(content(r)$headers)`  show the Accept and Authorization headers?

Comment: And instead of explicitly setting the `Accept` header, you could use `accept_json()`, as shown here: https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/content_type.html